# MATLAB -- Can't display video with GUIDE

Tags: matlab-guide

I want to display a video of my choice in an user interface using GUIDE. To do that I have a pushbutton to choose the video and an axis to display it.

According to Matlab I don't have mistakes and I looked around to find solutions without success...

```
% --- Executes on button press in ouvrir.
    function ouvrir_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to ouvrir (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA

    % Ask the user what video he wants to load
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.avi'},'File Selector');
    fullPathname = strcat(pathname, filename);
    disp(fullPathname);
    set(handles.text2, 'String', filename);

    %display the video in the axis
    video = vision.VideoFileReader(fullPathname);
    while ~isDone(video)
        frame = step(video);
        showFrameOnAxis(handles.axes1,frame);
    end
```

When I launch my programm, i can load the file and it displays it well but the axis just diseapear...

If you could help me a litle it would be great !
Sincerely yours.

edit : Do you recommend me to create my own UI ?

Comment: Might be a codec problem? Unfortunately I don't have the toolbox to try your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're try this. It's show and play video in axes.

```
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader(filename);
while ~isDone(videoFReader)
      frame = step(videoFReader);
      showFrameOnAxis(handles.axes,frame);
end
```